# Beamer ignoring table format?

Tags: tables, beamer, packages

I have a number of tables formatted in a LaTeX document. I want to put these tables into a beamer class with one table/slide and perserve the table formatting. When I compile my document, everything behaves as expected, however my tables do not maintain their original formatting. Specifically, I do not see my `bottomrule` lines. Here is my MWE:

```
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\documentclass{beamer} 
\title{Here is my Title} 
\author{drbunsen} 
\date{October 1st, 2011} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{My Slide Title}
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5px}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} \bottomrule
H1 & H2 & H3 & H4 & H5 & H6 & H7\\ \bottomrule
a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\
& 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is my caption}
\end{table}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

How can I perserve my LaTeX table formatting/styling in beamer? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load the packages (`booktabs`, `caption`) after `\documentclass`, not before.

I can confirm that errors are produced and lines are missing if you load in the wrong order. However, in the right order all is fine:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
```

[image: table on beamer slide]